# Xamarin with SQL Server and Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, xamarin.android, entity-framework-6

How do I use Entity Framework in a Xamarin Android solution? I have an existing DAL project, but I think it's a problem between "normal" and Core and I'm pretty lost.

I know it's an "open" question and I hope you will forgive me.

I'm trying to migrate a web solution to an Android app and my experience with app's are very, very limited (for now) :(

Comment: It's a trick question: the answer is "**you don't**". Excepting on-prem LoB applications, end-user-facing applications don't connect directly to a database server over the Internet: instead they typically interface with a backend web-service of some-kind, and it's that web-service that would use EF and connect directly to SQL Server.

Comment: So, If I understand you correctly

1) Create and WebService
2) Use REST from App

How to implement "EntityFramework-like-methods" in App then?

Comment: ^Bingo, an API should be the interface between your Xamarin app and your SQL Server database.

Comment: @Stronghold There is no requirement that a backend service is HTTP-based and RESTful.

Comment: @Stronghold _"How to implement "EntityFramework-like-methods" in App then?"_ - you don't. EF is for working with databases, not web-services. A well-built web-service will have some kind of service-metadata (e.g. WSDL, Swagger, etc) that allows tooling to generate client services, DTO types, and more for whatever language and platform you're using.

Comment: Any ideas on how to implement the REST result to a workable "entifyframework" look-a-like?

Comment: @Stronghold Why are you so _obsessed_ with "REST" and EF? Those are fine-details that are irrelevant when you're at early planning stages.

Comment: @Dai :( You lost me :( What is it you suggest me to do?

I do not mean WS or REST is nedded. I just thought that what you meant ::) Any solution is welcome

Comment: @Stronghold Pardon my asking, but what is your level of formal CS/SE education?

Comment: @Dai low enough to not knoving what you mean by SE ;-) CS (is .cs) I'm okay with :) (and do know that Xamarin is .net)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248819/discussion-between-stronghold-and-dai).

Comment: Did you check the official document about [Getting Started with EF Core and Xamarin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/xamarin)?

Comment: Yes @LiyunZhang-MSFT but got stuck. Now it seems that MAUI is a way better solution as it (should) provide .net 6 (7) support native :D